# how to configure datasources in wso2 IS as KM 5.9.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

How to configure datasources for WSO2_CARBON_DB, WSO2_MB_STORE_DB, WSO2_METRICS_DB, WSO2UM_DB in deployment.toml to change it from H2 to mysql? How to write correct records in deployment.toml? I added records for mysql, but IS still uses H2, not mysql, in master-datasources.xml configurations are for H2, not for mysql. My config:

```
[database.carbon]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://is.com:3306/WSO2CARBON_DB?autoReconnect=true"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"

[database.mb]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://is.com:3306/WSO2MB_DB?autoReconnect=true"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"

[database.metrics]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://is.com:3306/WSO2METRICS_DB?autoReconnect=true"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"

[database.WSO2UM_DB]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://is.com:3306/userdb?autoReconnect=true"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to configure CARBON_DB as this database has the internal data related to the product. This data is stored in the embedded H2 database. 
But a **SHARED_DB** has been introduced in the newer version, this database contains the registry and user management data. But as in the previous version, you can configure different databases for registry and user management.

You can configured **SHARED_DB** by adding following configuration:

```
[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reg_db"
username = "username"
password = "password"
```

You can configure **User management DB** by adding the configuration as:

```
[database.user]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://is.com:3306/userdb?autoReconnect=true"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"
```

For **UM_DB**, if you want to add additional properties, you can add parameters in following format:

```
pool_options.maxActive = 50
pool_options.maxWait = 60000
pool_options.defaultAutoCommit = false
```

To configure other databases, you can follow the approach mentioned below. For example, to configure **MB_DB**, add following configuration:

```
[[datasource]]
id = "WSO2_MB_STORE_DB"
url = "jdbc:mysql://is.com:3306/WSO2MB_DB?autoReconnect=true"
username = "username"
password = "password"
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
pool_options.maxActive = 50
pool_options.maxWait = 60000
pool_options.validationInterval = 30000
pool_options.defaultAutoCommit = false
```

Comment: I added strings id="WSO2_MB_STORE_DB" and id="WSO2_METRICS_DB". After that i have 2 datasources for WSO2_MB_STORE_DB and WSO2_METRICS_DB. 1st for H2, 2nd for mysql. How to remove datasources for H2 db?

Comment: It's better to change WSO2CARBON_DB to mysql, cause i had problems with h2 when i backed up working system, so i want to go away from it.

Comment: i dont need configuration for SHARED_DB, cause documentation for IS has example how to configure it. Thanks!

Comment: any help please? **How to remove datasources for H2 db and to change WSO2CARBON_DB to mysql?**

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problems setting up the dbs for WSO2 API manager 3.0.0: I can add mysql type datasources for MB_STORE_DB and CARBON_DB but H2 types still alive in master-datasources.xml.

By the way it is not clear for me if the carbon DB needs or not to be shared between nodes while configuring an Active-Active Deployment solution.

Thanks, Bernard

Comment: i got answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59207493/is-it-advised-to-use-different-database-for-identity-shared-bps-consent-metric]

Comment: readinf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068915/wso2-apim-3-0-0-mb-store-databaseit's seems the MB

Comment: it seems we need to modify the master-datasource template file in resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml.j2

Comment: i changed datasources in master-datasources.xml.j2, it worked, now i use mysql for carbon and mbstore DBs, Thx. But there is no metrics-datasources.xml.j2, so how to change datasource for metrics DB?

Comment: i created metrics-datasources.xml.j2 with mysql datasource, so now all dbs on mysql.

Comment: On my side I edited directly the "metrics-datasources.xml" file  which is not subject of a template, so its content is not modified at startup.