# Is it advised to use different database for identity,shared,bps,consent & metric db in wsois 5.9.0?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Is it advised to use different database for identity,shared,bps,consent & metric db in wsois 5.9.0? how to configure consent and metric db?

I am trying this configuration:

```
[user_store]
type = "database"
TenantManager="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager"
ReadOnly=false
ReadGroups=true
WriteGroups=true
scim_enabled = true                                                             #enabling scim apis

[database.user]
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/regdb?useSSL=false"
username = "regadmin"
password = "regadmin"
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

[realm_manager]
data_source = "WSO2USER_DB"

[database.identity_db]
type = "mysql"
url= "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/regdb?useSSL=false"
username = "regadmin"
password = "regadmin"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url= "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/regdb?useSSL=false"
username = "regadmin"
password = "regadmin"

[bps_database.config]
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bepl_db?useSSL=false"
username = "regadmin"
password = "regadmin"
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

[[datasource]]
id="WSO2CONSENT_DB"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bepl_db?useSSL=false"
username = "regadmin"
password = "regadmin"
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
jmx_enable=false

[carbon_health_check]
enable= true

[keystore.primary]
name = "wso2carbon.jks"
password = "wso2carbon"
```

What is the correct dbscripts import order and whether they can be in different databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Identity server comes with an embedded H2 database. 
    But WSO2 recommends changing this to any production level database. 
    By refering to your configuration i can see that you are trying to change it to 
    a mysql database.

You are using a database called **regdb** for identity and shared database.
and for consent management and bps database you are using a different database called **bepl_db**.

Hence you will have to execute the following DB scrips as per the documentation for **regdb**.

```
     - <IS-HOME>/dbscripts/identity/mysql.sql
     - <IS-HOME>/dbscripts/identity/uma/mysql.sql
     - <IS-HOME>/dbscripts/mysql.sql
```

you will have to execute the following DB scrips as per the documentation for **bepl_db**.

```
    - <IS-HOME>/dbscripts/consent/mysql.sql
    - <IS-HOME>/dbscripts/bps/bpel/create/mysql.sql
```

Please note that if you do not have a clustered enviroment you also have the option of storing the consent data in IDENTITY_DB

If so you can execute the

```
    - <IS-HOME>/dbscripts/consent/mysql.sql
```

script against the **regdb** not against the **bepl_db**. and remove the below config from deployment.toml

```
    [[datasource]]
    id="WSO2CONSENT_DB"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bepl_db?useSSL=false"
    username = "regadmin"
    password = "regadmin"
    driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jmx_enable=false
```

Also, you only need to refer this documentation if you have a requirement of using the workflow feature.
       https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/changing-datasource-bpsds/

And you only need to refer this documentation if you have a clustered setup 
       https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/changing-datasource-consent-management/

Otherwise only follow https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/changing-to-mysql/
documentation and that will be perfectly enough.

Also, metric db is deprecating since 5.9 hence do not worry about pointing its data to a different database.

Comment: Can u help me How to configure datasources for WSO2_CARBON_DB, WSO2_MB_STORE_DB, WSO2_METRICS_DB to change it from H2 to mysql? I tried to change it with [[datasource]], I added strings id="WSO2_MB_STORE_DB",id="WSO2_METRICS_DB". After that i have 2 datasources for WSO2_MB_STORE_DB and WSO2_METRICS_DB. 1st for H2, 2nd for mysql. How to remove datasources for H2 db?

Comment: why you have a requirement of changing WSO2_METRICS_DB

Comment: WSO recommends not to use H2 db in production environment, and i had problems with backup of working WSO2 systems, so i want to go away from H2 and to use mysql db for all WSO2 DBS.

Comment: what is your IS version?

Comment: IS 5.9.0 as Key Manager

Comment: Then you do not need to change WSO2_CARBON_DB, WSO2_MB_STORE_DB, WSO2_METRICS_DB from h2 to mysql.  You need to only change WSO2_IDENTITY_DB and WSO2_SHARED_DB Please refer to the official documentation https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/changing-to-mysql/

Comment: ok, thx, but documentation doesn't tell anything about carbon, mb store, metrics dbs.

Comment: thats because they have deprecated mb store, metrics dbs databases from IS-5.9 and carbon_db contains internal data you will be not needed to point it to another db